# variables not changing when I add an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I made this code, and when you pick a blueberry, your blueberries stay at one, and I dont know why. I want the user to acquire multiple blueberries, but it seems to stay at one.

```
def blueberryfound(blueberries):
    print("        .-~~~~-.")
    print("       /  ( ( ' \ ")
    print("      | ( )   )  | ")
    print("      \ ) ' }  / /")
    print("       \,,,,,,,,/")
    leaveorpick = input("Enter P to pick or L to leave the blueberry!").lower()
    if leaveorpick == "p":
        print("")
        print("You chose to keep the berry.")
        blueberries = blueberries + 1
        print("You now have",blueberries,"blueberries.")
```

Comment: It works fine for me when called with `blueberryfound(1)`. When I enter `p`, I get `You now have 2 blueberries.`

Comment: You should add how you call the function and comment on what you expect on the last print statement. So you call the function with blueberries=1 and the last print prints out 1?

Answer (score 1):

`integer` variables are immutable, this means

```
def blueberryfound(val):
    val = val + 1

blueberries = 1
blueberryfound(blueberries)
```

does not work. Only `val` inside the function will be incremented, the outside variable `blueberries` will not be changed. instead you can do

```
def blueberryfound(val):
    return val + 1

blueberries = 1
blueberries = blueberryfound(blueberries)
```

Alternatively you can use an object-oriented approach, where a player object has a number of properties, `blueberries` being one of them. Your functions can then manipulate all the properties of a given player instance.

```
class Player(object):
    blueberries = 0

def blueberryfound(player):
    player.blueberries += 1

player = Player()
blueberryfound(player)
```